# How to use socket after connect event in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sockets, socket.io

sorry for my english.
There is a problem. Inside my app.js server, I added sockets, I use the join event, inside 'connection' event is a function that takes a socket as a parameter, however, I want to push the user into a room, but the name of this room is available inside the model of my REST API part of the server (from the session).
Question. How can I take and push a user who has connected to the right room inside my REST API model? (this model and its service are fired whenever a user requests a page, let's say an analogue of an authorization check). In addition to this problem, there is another service and model that are responsible for adding, for example, some kind of task, this is also a REST API, and so inside this model I would like to send messages to all the necessary users in sockets that a task has been added, EXCEPT the sender himself At the moment I can't do anything at all. It is sent to everyone in general, including the sender, the socket from the connection cannot be thrown in the REST API model
App.js

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  app.set('socket', socket);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.disconnect(true);
  });
});
```

Controller that sends data to all services, and those in the model

```
const controller = (ServiceClass, params) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        const service = new ServiceClass({
            session: req.session,
            sessionId: req.sessionID,
            cookies: req.cookies,
            socketIo: req.app.get('socketio'),
            socket: req.app.get('socket'),
        });

        const response = await service.run(params(req));
        res.json(response);
    };
}

export default controller;
```

Inside the model that fires on every request to the site from the user, here I'm trying to give the right room

```
export default class IsLoggedService extends Service {
    constructor(context) {
        super(context);
    }

    async execute() {
    
    this.context.socket
      .join(`room${userSession.roleId}`);
    }
}
```

I send information to the client about the created task also from the rest api service + model

```
    this.context.socket
            .to(`room${userSession.roleId}`)
            .emit('test', 'test');
```

I have already reviewed the entire socket.io documentation, it says everywhere that in order to send a message to everyone except yourself, you need to use a socket, but this does not work at all, it is sent to everyone, including the sender, I also tried to achieve a socket inside the service and model, all to no avail

Answer (score 0):

The most logical implementation method is that you receive all the user through the json object that you receive when sending a message through the socket and implement the logic of the program according to the data.